# How to export loads of MysQL record in CSV in chunks in Python?

Tags: python, namecheap

TO clarify, I am on a shared hosting so `mysqldump` and `OUTFILE` is not available for me, at least on NameCheap hosting. I am using the following code

```
def fetch(connection, id_count, offset):
    records = None
    try:
        if connection is not None:
            with connection.cursor(dictionary=True) as cursor:
                sql = "SELECT * FROM options_data WHERE id > {} LIMIT {},3000".format(id_count, offset)
                print(sql)
                cursor.execute(sql, records)
                records = cursor.fetchall()
            connection.commit()
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception in Store')
        print(ex)
    finally:
        return records
```

```
def get_connection(host, user, password, db_name):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host,
            user=user,
            use_unicode=True,
            password=password,
            database=db_name
        )
        connection.set_charset_collation('utf8')
        print('Connected')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
    finally:
        return connection
```

and then

```
connection = get_connection(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    if connection is None:
        print('Unable to connect MySQL Server')
        exit()

    result = []
    final_rercords = []
    idx = 0

    for x in range(0, 37206, 3000):
        idx += 1
        records = fetch(connection, x, x)
        for r in records:
            result.append(r['instrument_name'])
            result.append(str(r['m']))
            result.append(str(r['p']))
            result.append(str(r['e']))
            result.append(str(r['ts'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S')))
            final_rercords.append(','.join(result))
        with open('{}_options.csv'.format(idx), 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
            f.write('\n'.join(final_rercords))
            f.write('\n')

        with open('{}_options.csv'.format(idx), 'rb') as f_in:
            with gzip.open('{}_options.csv.gz'.format(idx), 'wb') as f_out:
                shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
        print('{}_options.csv.gz created'.format(idx))
        sleep(1)
```

I noticed it is not the SQL Query but the process of iterating records and then dumping into a CSV file is taking both time and memory. On Namecheap the script is killed on a higher limit.

Comment: Using pandas to read data in chunks and exporting the data frame to csv?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large result set, don't use `cursor.fetchall()`. That requires the entire result set to be downloaded and stored in memory in the Python process.

I understand that the way you have written your functions, you fetch all the rows in your `fetch()` function, then return that set of rows from the function. This *requires* that you use `fetchall()` in the function. But you shouldn't do that if it takes too much memory.

Also you use double the memory when you copy the entire result into your `final_records` list.

Instead, you should fetch one row at a time. Write out the results to a CSV file immediately in the same loop that you use to fetch the rows one by one. This makes the memory requirement no more than a single row, no matter how many rows are in the result set.

You may also find it useful to use the Python csv package.

The simplest form would look like the following:

```
cursor.execute(sql, records)
for row in cursor:
  csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

In that example, the csvwriter is an object created with [csv.writer()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer). You should read more about that package. You can optionally use an open gzip file handle as the file to write to, and you can use the csv.DictWriter subclass, etc.

Comment: I tried another way,  I tried `csv`'s `writerows` and and assigned resultset, it instantly increased the performance.